# How to make an array of images specifically in the same <ul>?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an image switcher for my portfolio site that is unique. To do this I think I need to be able to have an array of images that matches with the corresponding array of list items with the names of the projects they belong to, like this:

```
<ul>
<li><img src="1.png"></li>
<li><img src="2.png"></li>
<li><img src="3.png"></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Project 1</li>
<li>Project 2</li>
<li>Project 3</li>
</ul>
```

So I guess I want the javascript to "think" like this: "Oh, img 2 is the second list item, if project 2 is clicked which is also the second list item, I should display img 2"

Ya digg?

Here is what I have so far, if you need a visual:
http://addproxy.net/sites/img_switcher/index.html

Comment: And what progress have you made so far in trying to solve this problem? What issues did you encounter with your code? Something you would like to ask about here?

Comment: I just posted a link to what I have done so far. I would like to ask how to do that ^^^, the arrays, linking them

Comment: nice, now that's much better in terms of asking a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery, you could do it like this:

HTML:

```
<ul id="images">
    <li><img src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344291068_HdnTo-Ti.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344290962_h6JjS-Ti.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344290837_ypsKL-Ti.jpg"></li>
</ul>

<ul id="projects">
    <li>Project 1</li>
    <li>Project 2</li>
    <li>Project 3</li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
$("#projects li").click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
    var $images = $("#images li");
    $images.hide();  // hide previous images
    $images.eq(pos).show();
});
```

And, you can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gV2NH/.

If you can't use jQuery, then the general idea is that you set up a click handler for each project.  When one of them is clicked on, you get the parent and get it's children (which will be a list of all the project li tags).  You then see which one the click happened on so now you have the sequence number.  You can then use that sequence number to show just the right image from the other list.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This exactly like what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Since you're relatively new here, do you realize that it's your responsibility to upvote (click on the up arrow) for answers to your questions that gave you helpful information and if one, in particular, answers your question best, click on the checkmark to mark it as the most helpful answer?  That's also the reward to people that helped you (they get stack overflow reputation points).